# cannot create link in php, showing "array" instead, ajax involved too

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a "link" out of the search results created. Currently if I search "A" all results that have an A in it are shown, but shown as just text, I can highlight the text etc but can't "click" it. I have tried to make it into a link through php but it doesn't work. Any help please? Code is shown below:

php code:

```
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row.="<a href = 'new.php'>['carMake']</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

These results are shown through a OnKeyUp function (xmlhttp etc). The above code, everytime I search it says "Array['carMake'].

Thanks.

Comment: `echo $row.="<a href = 'new.php'>\['carMake'\]</a>";`

Comment: just tried this, same error, "Array['carMake'], except with the slashes now...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard knowing exactly what you need here without seeing the structure of your `$row` array, but it sounds like you need to loop through this (since it is an array).

Maybe something like this?

```
foreach($row AS $car) {
   echo "<a href = 'new.php'>" . $car['carMake'] . "</a>";
}
```

If `$row` on the other hand is an array of car attributes (and not an array of cars), then perhaps something like this:

```
echo "<a href = 'new.php'>" . $row['carMake'] . "</a>";
```

If neither of these are what you need, update your question and show the output of `print_r($row)`. That'll help us see what you're trying to do better.

Comment: Awesome! That worked!! But do you know if there is any way to make the links not underlined?

Comment: That's a css question. `a { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: Yep will do but can't click it at the moment

Answer (score 0):

$row is an array of result? try this:

```
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href = 'new.php'>{$row['carMake']}</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```